# array in variable but error while using condition

Tags: php

I am trying to condition `if` one of these has `null` value, then else but i am getting error:

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
>   Undefined variable: average_winning_trade

`DD(winning_trades_profit)` result : []

here is the code for condition:

```
 if(!empty($losing_trades_loss   && $profitable_trades  && $winning_trades_profit   && $losing_trades)) {
              $average_winning_trade = round(array_sum($winning_trades_profit) / $profitable_trades);
              $average_losing_trade = array_sum($losing_trades_loss) / $losing_trades;
              $payoff_ratio_per_trade = abs(round($average_winning_trade / $average_losing_trade, 2));
          }else  { $payoff_ratio_per_trade ="0";}
```

Comment: Your error is caused elsewhere in your code where you try to use the variable $average_winning_trade while it's not defined as your error tells you.

Comment: Is a bitwise operation intended in this case? You're making comparisons with & instead of &&, is that intended?

Comment: result is null `DD(winning_trades_profit) result : []`, yet why php break my condition? @killstreet

Comment: this IF statement MUST GO INTO A SEPARATE FUNCTION. Please. Please refactor it. You will debug it as you do. YOu will find your problm and solve it!

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati as I stated earlier, the error is not within this if statement. Elsewhere in your code you are trying to call the $average_winning_trade variable, but if your if-statement fails, the $average_winning_trade will never be set.

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati can you also add the full else statement to your question? This will help aswell.

Comment: I dont want to set `$average_winning_trade ` if any of 4 variable is null value. .... i have null value then why it trying to set value? @killstreet

Comment: that is my full `else` statement. actually, if-statement moved to else but... its not happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your `if` condition:

```
if(!empty($losing_trades_loss   && $profitable_trades  && $winning_trades_profit   && $losing_trades))
```

because `$losing_trades_loss   && $profitable_trades  && $winning_trades_profit   && $losing_trades` is a boolean expression, it will always return true or false, and so `empty()` will always return false, so regardless of the state of those variables, the first part of your if statement will execute.

I think what you actually want is

```
if (isset($losing_trades_loss, $profitable_trades, $winning_trades_profit, $losing_trades))
```

or possibly

```
if (isset($losing_trades, $profitable_trades) && count($winning_trades_profit) && count($losing_trades_loss))
```

without seeing the rest of your code it's difficult to say which of the above would be correct.

**Edit**

You probably also need to change your assignments to check for 0 divisors:

```
$average_winning_trade = $profitable_trades ? round(array_sum($winning_trades_profit) / $profitable_trades) : 0;
$average_losing_trade = $losing_trades ? array_sum($losing_trades_loss) / $losing_trades : 0;
$payoff_ratio_per_trade = $average_losing_trade ? abs(round($average_winning_trade / $average_losing_trade, 2)) : 1;
```

Comment: You are right, but after using your code : error changed: ` ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Division by zero`

Comment: You also need to check for 0 divisors. See my edit. I've specified payoff ratio as 1 if there are no losing trades, but you might want a different result.

Comment: Thanks i learnt form you code. it worked perfectly but why did you given me -ve vote?

Comment: I most definitely did not give you a downvote! There is nothing wrong with your question.

Comment: thanks I really learnt it. from -ve vote, i ll unable to ask question from stackoverflow.

Comment: I've upvoted to bring you back to 0 for this question.

Answer (score 0):

As your error code shows

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined variable: average_winning_trade

Meaning you are trying to call the variable somewhere else in your code while it hasn't been set yet. This could be either before or after you reach the if-statement you put here. However, this if-statement is not causing the error to appear.

**UPDATE**

Your current if-statement is as follow:

IF NOT EMPTY $losing_trades_loss AND $profitable_trades AND $Winning_trades

but you clearly want

IF NOT EMPTY $losing_trades_loss OR $poritable_trades OR $winning_trades

so update your if-statement as follow:

```
if(!empty(
    $losing_trades_loss || 
    $profitable_trades || 
    $winning_trades_profit || 
    $losing_trades)) {
          $average_winning_trade = round(array_sum($winning_trades_profit) / $profitable_trades);
          $average_losing_trade = array_sum($losing_trades_loss) / $losing_trades;
          $payoff_ratio_per_trade = abs(round($average_winning_trade / $average_losing_trade, 2));
      }else  { $payoff_ratio_per_trade ="0";}
```

Comment: `If(!empty()) {} else{}`, i am saying its empty... then why is not moving on `else`?

Comment: Your using the conditions wrong, replace the && with ||

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati See updated answer

Comment: i have changed it but error changed `Division by zero`

Comment: This would also be caused by code outside this if-else-statement. Please include code below this if-statement or open a new question.

Comment: @killstreet the use of `empty` with any sort of boolean expression is incorrect, it will always return false.